# Disconnecting a boost signals2 connection by functor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-function, boost-signals2

I'm trying to convert some code that used a different system over to use Boost.Signals2.  The old code used a regular function pointer as the functor; connections were done by calling a particular method with the functor, and disconnections were done by calling another method with the exact same functor.  For compatibility reasons I still want to support this, even though I know it's not the most efficient method under Signals2.

```
namespace bs2 = boost::signals2;
class Foo
{
    typedef bs2::signal<void (const Foo *foo)> UpdateEvent;
    UpdateEvent m_UpdateEvent;

public:
    typedef UpdateEvent::slot_type UpdateCallback;

    bs2::connection Register(const UpdateCallback& callback)
    {
        return m_UpdateEvent.connect(callback);
    }

    void Unregister(const UpdateCallback& callback)
    {
        m_UpdateEvent.disconnect(callback);
    }
};
```

The above (simplified) code works fine for the connection, but the Unregister method won't compile in VS2008:

```
T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function_equal.hpp(17) : error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Foo::UpdateCallback' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_base.hpp(808): could be 'bool boost::operator ==<T>(const boost::function_base &,Functor)'
    with
    [
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        Functor=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_base.hpp(817): or       'bool boost::operator ==<F>(Functor,const boost::function_base &)'
    with
    [
        F=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        Functor=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\guiddef.h(192): or       'int operator ==(const GUID &,const GUID &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_base.hpp(746): or       'bool boost::operator ==(const boost::function_base &,boost::detail::function::useless_clear_type *)'
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_base.hpp(758): or       'bool boost::operator ==(boost::detail::function::useless_clear_type *,const boost::function_base &)'
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/blank.hpp(58): or       'bool boost::operator ==(const boost::blank &,const boost::blank &)'
    while trying to match the argument list '(const Foo::UpdateCallback, const Foo::UpdateCallback)'
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function_equal.hpp(24) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::function_equal_impl<F,G>(const F &,const G &,long)' being compiled
    with
    [
        F=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        G=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_base.hpp(811) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::function_equal<Functor,Functor>(const F &,const G &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        Functor=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        F=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        G=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp(527) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::operator ==<T>(const boost::function_base &,Functor)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        Functor=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp(221) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::signals2::detail::signal1_impl<R,T1,Combiner,Group,GroupCompare,SlotFunction,ExtendedSlotFunction,Mutex>::do_disconnect<T>(const T &,boost::mpl::bool_<C_>)' being compiled
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T1=const Foo *,
        Combiner=boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>,
        Group=int,
        GroupCompare=std::less<int>,
        SlotFunction=boost::function<void (const Foo *)>,
        ExtendedSlotFunction=boost::function<void (const boost::signals2::connection &,const Foo *)>,
        Mutex=boost::signals2::mutex,
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        C_=false
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp(691) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::signals2::detail::signal1_impl<R,T1,Combiner,Group,GroupCompare,SlotFunction,ExtendedSlotFunction,Mutex>::disconnect<T>(const T &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T1=const Foo *,
        Combiner=boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>,
        Group=int,
        GroupCompare=std::less<int>,
        SlotFunction=boost::function<void (const Foo *)>,
        ExtendedSlotFunction=boost::function<void (const boost::signals2::connection &,const Foo *)>,
        Mutex=boost::signals2::mutex,
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    .\Foo.cpp(72) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::signals2::signal1<R,T1,Combiner,Group,GroupCompare,SlotFunction,ExtendedSlotFunction,Mutex>::disconnect<Foo::UpdateCallback>(const T &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T1=const Foo *,
        Combiner=boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>,
        Group=int,
        GroupCompare=std::less<int>,
        SlotFunction=boost::function<void (const Foo *)>,
        ExtendedSlotFunction=boost::function<void (const boost::signals2::connection &,const Foo *)>,
        Mutex=boost::signals2::mutex,
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
```

So, somehow the function object can't be compared to itself?  I also tried using slot_function_type for the UpdateCallback, as well as explicitly specifying it as a boost::function with the same signature; both of those produced this error instead:

```
T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp(527) : error C2666: 'boost::signals2::detail::operator ==' : 4 overloads have similar conversions
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_template.hpp(997): could be 'void boost::operator ==<R,T0>(const boost::function1<R,T0> &,const boost::function1<R,T0> &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T0=const Foo *
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_base.hpp(817): or       'bool boost::operator ==<boost::function<Signature>>(Functor,const boost::function_base &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
    with
    [
        Signature=void (const Foo *),
        Functor=boost::function<void (const Foo *)>
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/function/function_base.hpp(808): or       'bool boost::operator ==<T>(const boost::function_base &,Functor)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
    with
    [
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        Functor=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    or       'built-in C++ operator==(void (__thiscall boost::function1<R,T0>::dummy::* )(void), void (__thiscall boost::function1<R,T0>::dummy::* )(void))'
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T0=const Foo *
    ]
    while trying to match the argument list '(boost::function<Signature>, const Foo::UpdateCallback)'
    with
    [
        Signature=void (const Foo *)
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp(221) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::signals2::detail::signal1_impl<R,T1,Combiner,Group,GroupCompare,SlotFunction,ExtendedSlotFunction,Mutex>::do_disconnect<T>(const T &,boost::mpl::bool_<C_>)' being compiled
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T1=const Foo *,
        Combiner=boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>,
        Group=int,
        GroupCompare=std::less<int>,
        SlotFunction=boost::function<void (const Foo *)>,
        ExtendedSlotFunction=boost::function<void (const boost::signals2::connection &,const Foo *)>,
        Mutex=boost::signals2::mutex,
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback,
        C_=false
    ]
    T:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/signals2/detail/signal_template.hpp(691) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::signals2::detail::signal1_impl<R,T1,Combiner,Group,GroupCompare,SlotFunction,ExtendedSlotFunction,Mutex>::disconnect<T>(const T &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T1=const Foo *,
        Combiner=boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>,
        Group=int,
        GroupCompare=std::less<int>,
        SlotFunction=boost::function<void (const Foo *)>,
        ExtendedSlotFunction=boost::function<void (const boost::signals2::connection &,const Foo *)>,
        Mutex=boost::signals2::mutex,
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
    .\Foo.cpp(72) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::signals2::signal1<R,T1,Combiner,Group,GroupCompare,SlotFunction,ExtendedSlotFunction,Mutex>::disconnect<Foo::UpdateCallback>(const T &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        R=void,
        T1=const Foo *,
        Combiner=boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>,
        Group=int,
        GroupCompare=std::less<int>,
        SlotFunction=boost::function<void (const Foo *)>,
        ExtendedSlotFunction=boost::function<void (const boost::signals2::connection &,const Foo *)>,
        Mutex=boost::signals2::mutex,
        T=Foo::UpdateCallback
    ]
```

So I guess it's gone from too few choices to too many.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: Take a look at the two following links: 1) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/function/faq.html#id1549884  2) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1530326

Comment: Well, I guess that might explain why it doesn't work directly, but not how to make it work.

Comment: Two years later, I have the same question. I'll post an answer if I find one.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up giving up on that idea and modified the calling code to save the `connection` as a `scoped_connection` instead.

Comment: This problem is discussed in previously. Most simple way to solve this problem is using typedef + regular function pointer.       typedef void (*Slot) (const Foo *foo);

Comment: That's what I had originally, but as indicated I wanted to use Signals2 to allow additional state to be conveyed.

Answer (score 0):

boost::function doesn't implement operator==, so we can not make comparison like f1 == f2.
This cause problem in boost::signal library when we need to disconnect a function from signal
by using boost::function as parameter. boost::signal tries to find function by comparing parameter with its own functions and it causes error. My solution is below. Other possible solutions are proposed as well such as storing connections .... If my approach fits you, you should choose it because it doesn't store anything so you don't need deal with manual connection management.

```
class Button {
public:

    typedef void (*EventHandler)();
    typedef boost::signal<void ()> Event;

    Button () {
    }

    virtual ~Button () {
    }

    void addClickHandler(EventHandler handler) {
        clickEvent.connect(handler);
    }

    void removeClickHandler(EventHandler handler) {
        clickEvent.disconnect(handler);
    }

    void click() {
        clickEvent();
    }

private:
    Event clickEvent;
};

void print() {
    cout << "print" << endl;
}

void app1_TestButton() {
    Button b;
    b.addClickHandler(print);
    b.click();

    b.removeClickHandler(print);
    b.click();
}
```

Comment: This is not really a solution as it only works with a bare function pointer, which by definition cannot include any context, and is therefore basically useless in a real application where you can't rely on global singletons.